# Use chebyshev's inequality to show that $P(S>22)\geq73/80$ and Use the central limit theorem to estimate $P(S>22)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

I am struggling to solve this problem but don't know how to do it. Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Let's roll $12$ fair, six-sided dice. Let $S$ denote the sum of the results.

(i) Use chebyshev's inequality to show that $P(S>22)\geq73/80$

(ii) Use the central limit theorem to estimate $P(S>22)$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know where to begin.

Comment: A good start would be to calculate the expected value and the variance of $S$.

Comment: I did part (i). kindly also help me in part (ii)